# confused by tutorial/example on uniform convergence of $\zeta(x)=\sum 1/n^x$

Tags: uniform-convergence, riemann-zeta

I am confused by a tutorial/example on uniform convergence of $\zeta(x)=\sum 1/n^x$.

The source is a reputable and widely used website: https://brilliant.org/wiki/uniform-convergence/. An screenshot is replicated below for convenience. Note: the example given is for real, not complex, $x$.

The steps are as follows:

- The Weierstrass M-test says that if $\sum M_n<\infty$ where $|f_n(x)|\leq M_n$, then $\sum f_n(x)$ converges **uniformly**.
- Fix $a>1$, and note that $|1/n^x|=1/n^x \leq 1/n^a$ where $x\geq a$.
- So the M-test tells us that $\sum 1/n^x$ converges uniformly for $x \geq a$.

Note that I have said $x\geq a$, not $x>a$ as per the tutorial. I think I am correct (?).

This logic can be extended easily from real $x$ to complex $s$. That is, $\sum 1/n^s$ converges uniformly for $\Re(s) \geq a$, where $a>1$.

**Question:** why does this tutorial, and other sources, not say the uniform convergence is over $x>1$. Why do they separate the conditions into $x \geq a$ and $ a>1$? In my mind the two are equivalent.

The context for this question is that uniform converge of a series where each term is holomorphic means the infinite sum is also holomorphic, and I wan to be able to use this to say the Dirichlet series for $\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic for $\Re(s)>1$

**Note:** My previous questions have not been well formulated, so I am hoping this one is.

[image]

Comment: The sum does not converge uniformly on $(1, \infty)$. It does converge uniformly on $[a, \infty)$ for all $a > 1$. The two are not the same. On a related but possibly simpler topic: Consider the function $f : (0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ defined as $f(x) = 1/x$. Then, $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$ but it is uniformly continuous on every interval of the form $[a, \infty)$ for $a > 0$.

Comment: A more tractable example for uniform convergence is the following: Consider the sequence of functions $f_n : [0, 1) \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f_n(x) = x^n$. Then, $(f_n)_n$ converges to the zero function on $[0, a]$ for every $0 < a < 1$ but not on $[0, 1)$.

Comment: hi @AryamanMaithani - thanks for trying to help. When you say the sum does not converge uniformly on $(1,\infty)$, I'm not sure I agree because $x=1$ is excluded from that domain. I would agree it doesn't converge on $[1,\infty)$. What am I missing?

Comment: similarly for your second example $x^n$, the functions sequence converges at $[0,1)$ but not $[0,1]$. Obviously I'm not understanding something basic ...

Comment: There is a difference between converging for every $x$ in the domain and *uniform convergence*. Are you aware of this?

Comment: hi @AryamanMaithani I do understand the definition of *uniform* convergence. The difference between the partial sums/sequence and the actual limit can be made less than $\epsilon$ with a large enough number of terms $N$ and this does not depend on $x$. I can't see how this helps .. if you can make the connection then I think we'll have cracked it. In my opinion, $x^n$ converges uniformly for all $0 \leq x < 1$ which is $[0,1)$.

Comment: what $N$ will you choose for $\epsilon = 1/2$?

Comment: hi @AryamanMaithani - ok so the N depends on $x$, and therefore the series is not uniformly convergent. The trouble I'm having is that $a$ can be chosen to be arbitrarily close to 1, effectively making the two domain options the same, $[0,1)$ and $[0,a]$ where $a<1$. If $a$ can be arbitrarily close to 1, but not equal 1, then the two domains are the same?

Comment: No, they are not the same. Once you fix $a$, then given any $\epsilon$, you can choose $N$ to be anything that makes $a^N < \epsilon$ (and such an $N$ does exist) and this will show uniform convergence on $[0, a]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe reason why they're not equivalent is because of the dependencies of quantifiers. Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of complex-valued functions defined on $(1,\infty)$, and let $f:(1,\infty)\to\Bbb{C}$ be a given function.

- $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is uniformly convergent on $(1,\infty)$ to $f$ by definition means the following: for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$, if $n\geq N$ then $\sup\limits_{x\in (1,\infty)}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.
- For every $a>1$, $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,\infty)$ means by definition that: for every $a>1$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$, if $n\geq N$ then $\sup\limits_{x\in (a,\infty)}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Note that in the first case, $N$ depends only on $\epsilon$, but in the second case, it depends on $a$ and $\epsilon$. Therefore, the first condition implies the second, but the converse need not be true (and it's actually false).

---

We don't even have to talk about uniform convergence to highlight the mistake in logic you're making. Here are much simpler statements, which hopefully highlight the error in your logic:

> **False Statement 1.**
>
> Every natural number is finite, therefore $\Bbb{N}$ is a bounded set.

I hope no explanations are necessary as to why it is false. Here's another (essentially same logical error, just slightly more sophisticated):

> **False Statement 2.**
>
> Consider the function $f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. For every $\alpha>0$, $f$ is bounded on $[\alpha,\infty)$ (it is bounded by $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ since it is a decreasing function). Therefore, $f$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$.

Clearly this is an incorrect conclusion. Just sketch the graph of $f$ to see it is unbounded on $(0,\infty)$. Again, this is a matter of dependencies of quantifiers in the definition.

- To say $f$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$ means that there is an $M>0$ such that for all $x\in (0,\infty)$, $|f(x)|\leq M$.
- To say for each $\alpha>0$, $f$ is bounded on $[\alpha,\infty)$ means that for every $\alpha>0$ there is an $M>0$ such that for all $x\in [\alpha,\infty)$, we have $|f(x)|\leq M$.

---

The issue is that things like "boundedness" or "uniform convergence" are "global" properties, depending on the behavior of functions (or sequences of functions) on the whole domain of of the functions. Contrast this with things like "continuity" or "differentiability", which are "local properties", in the sense that if a function is continuous (resp differentiable, resp $C^{\infty}$) on $(a,\infty)$ for all $a>1$, then the function is continuous (resp differentiable, resp $C^{\infty}$) on $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: hi @peek-a-boo this is helpful. your false statement 2 was the most enlightening. I will go away and reconsider which such arguments are used to justify the dirichlet series for $\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic (from uniform convergence) for $\Re(s)>1$ and not $\Re(s)>a$ where $a>1$.

Comment: @Tariq as I mentioned in my final paragraph, diffetentiability (and thus holomorphy) are local properties. Since $\zeta$ is holomorphic on $\{\text{Re}(s) >a\}$ for all $a>1$ (a fact easily proved by Weierstrass M test), it is holomorphic on $\{\text{Re}(s) >1\}$.

Comment: thanks again @peek-a-boo - your input has been very helpful.

Comment: (+1) for the well-explained answer to a somewhat common question that students have on this topic.