# Partial sums of the Riemann zeta function and uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, riemann-zeta

For every $\delta\gt 0$, the partial sums of the Riemann zeta function $\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}$ converge uniformly on $S_{1+\delta}=\{s\in\mathbb{C}:\Re (s)\gt 1+\delta\}$. But the convergence is **not** uniform on the whole of $S_1=\{s\in\mathbb{C}:\Re (s)\gt 1\}$.

Now the fact that $\zeta$ is analytic on $S_{1+\delta}$ for every $\delta\gt 0$ **does** imply that $\zeta$ is analytic on the whole of $S_1$ – why? Where does this implication come from?

Comment: Uniform convergence and analyticity have definitions that differ in kind.

Comment: @MarkViola Can you please elaborate? I don't see why this solves the problem.

Comment: I suggest that you review the definitions.  Try and understand the distinctions.  Then, logically conclude.  HINT:  The order in which things happen make a difference.

Comment: What is the union of the closed sets $E_\delta=\{s\in \mathbb{C}: \text{Re}(s)\ge 1+\delta\}$ over $\delta>0$?  It is the opened set $\{s\in \mathbb{C}:\text{Re}(s)>1\}$.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, I understand that it is the union. But then why this logic with unions doesn't work for uniform convergence?

Comment: Analyticity (being a local property since a function is analytic on a domain iff it is analytic in the neighborhood of each point in the domain) follows from local uniform convergence; global uniform convergence is a much stronger property

Comment: It’s a local vs global issue. Existence of a limit (which is what differentiability is about) is a local matter, but uniform convergence is a global matter, as you see from the order of quantifiers in its definition. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4378253/568204) for further remarks and (non)examples.

Comment: @Conrad What exactly do you mean by "global uniform convergence" and "local uniform convergence"?

Comment: Local uniform convergence means uniform convergence on compacts in your domain (which is equivalent to uniform convergence on small enough discs around any point) and that clearly holds for the partial sums of RZ on $\Re s>1$ and more generally for the partial sums of any dirichlet series in the half plane of convergence (for any such point if one takes $a>0$ its distance to the abscissa of convergence, the partial sums converge uniformly on the disc centered at it with radius $a/2$ and less); global uniform convergence means uniform convergence on the full domain

Comment: For dirichlet series global uniform convergence of the partial sums even on the half plane of absolute convergence is a very strong property since dirichlet polynomials are bounded on any right half plane, so uniform convergence as above implies the dirichlet series is bounded on its half plane of absolute convergence and that is clearly not true for zeta but for example not for $1/\zeta$ either which is subtler